# Suppress tqdm output in Linux "screen" command log

Tags: python, gnu-screen, tqdm

I have a script which uses tqdm to make several progress bars for a lengthy processing workflow. Since the process is so lengthy, I use the "screen" command in Linux to run it as a detached process. I save the output to a log file via a command similar to:

```
screen -dm -L sh -c 'python3 myscript.py'
```

Because the output will also contains some reports which are valuable for analysis afterwards.

The problem is however the output log file from screen is heavily polluted by the many incrementally re-printed loading bars. But I do like being able to re-attach the process in a terminal so that I can intermittently monitor its progress. So I don't want to ditch tqdm entirely.

Is there a way to suppress the tqdm output in the log file after the fact, while still having it displaying "live" when running?

Comment: You could write your primary output to stdout and have tqdm write to stderr. Then redirect only stdout to file (see e.g. `tee`). Adding as a comment because I don't know how to make tqdm use stderr. BTW, I think you could remove `screen` from your question and it wouldn't change the essense.

Comment: @Norrius You are correct, and I have found out that tqdm uses stderr by default, probably for exactly this situation. So simply running the command in `tee` on a screen has the desired effect (e.g. `screen -dm -L sh -c 'python3 myscript.py | tee out.log | less'`). If you want to post this tip as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that it worked! Feel free to post the answer yourself (and accept it), this is totally ok. Maybe it helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to `screen` not being UTF-8 characters friendly. Try calling screen with -U argument: `screen -U -r <number>`
Also, when calling `tqdm`, try to include argument `ascii=True` in order to deal with screen not being UTF-8 friendly. Something like below:

```
for item in tqdm(items, total=len(items), ascii=True):
        pass
```

For your case, it is also a good practice to set the position of progress bar using `position` argument when calling `tqdm`.